# The directory "/.....public_html/generated/code/Magento" cannot be deleted Warning!rmdir(/.../public_html/generated/code/Magento): Directory not empty

Tags: permissions, file-permissions, file

```
Magento 2.4.2-p1
Smartwave Porto theme
extensions from Amasty
```

We have the Smartwave Porto theme. **It came with Mageplaza Layered Navigation** but an **old version**. Since we have some problems that I raised with Smartwave Porto, they suggested I would upgrade to the latest Mageplaza Layered Navigation version = layered-navigation_v4.1.1_m2_ce_mageplaza.

I have done that, and when running the following command afterwards:

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

**I get this Error:**

```
The directory "/home/myaccount/public_html/generated/code/Magento" cannot be deleted Warning!rmdir(/home/myaccount/public_html/generated/code/Magento): Directory not empty
```

I asked Mageplaza and said the following:

*...please run the command again with adding "sudo" at first.*

So I've tried the following:

```
sudo php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

and my Putty says the following:

*We trust you have received the usual lecture from the local System
Administrator. It usually boils down to these three things:*

```
#1) Respect the privacy of others.
#2) Think before you type.
#3) With great power comes great responsibility.
```

and asked for the password again. Once I entered the password - it gave the following Error:

*myaccount is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.*

When googling this topic, I found the following article:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52644737/i-cant-delete-the-folder-generated-code-in-magento-2-2-6

Here it says:

*www-data must be **owner of the project** if using Apache as web-server. Please execute commands given below:*

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data [path to magento directory]
navigate to root of your magento project
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
find ./var -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
find ./pub/media -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
find ./pub/static -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
chmod 777 ./app/etc
chmod 644 ./app/etc/*.xml
chmod u+x bin/magento
```

**We had a problem with ownership/permissions before. Is it safe for me run these in Putty via SSH on the account itself and/or ask our hosting company to do it for me?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run the command like this one :

```
sudo chmod -R 777 var/ generated/ pub/
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Comment: This works for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It's worth checking with your web host to see if the file permissions are set up correctly, however you should try to clear the generated/code directory first. Try clearing the directory manually before running the compile command:

```
rm -r generated/code/*
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

You can refer to the devdocs for more information about clearing directories during development:
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/howdoi/php/php_clear-dirs.html

Comment: This is a good solution but appears to be temporary as di:compile worked immediately after but the problem reappeared the next day.

Answer (score 0):

Should Change the folder permissions on own via chmod and chown